# Can I end a path on a dynamic segment with a file extension

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

Using rocket v0.5-rc I want to return HTML when `/leaderboard/2021` is requested, but JSON when `/leaderboard/2021.json` is requested. The year here should be dynamic.

I wrote the following two functions:

```rs
#[get("/leaderboard/<year>")]
fn get_leaderboard_year(year: u32) -> String {
    // ...
}

#[get("/leaderboard/<year>.json")]
fn get_leaderboard_year_json(year: u32) -> String {
    // ...
}
```

On the attribute for the JOSN function I get the following warning:
`` warning: `segment` starts with `<` but does not end with `>` `` 
`` help: perhaps you meant the dynamic parameter `<yearjson>`? ``

And, I guess as a result of that warning, I get an error on the type of `year`:
`` error[E0277]: the trait bound `i32: FromRequest<'_>` is not satisfied ``
`` the trait `FromRequest<'_>` is not implemented for `i32` ``

Can I, using one of the attriutes, make the distinction between file extension and no file extension?

Comment: The dynamic paths [documentation](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/requests/#dynamic-paths) doesn't seem to hint that this is supported. Maybe you could look at the year as a string and if it ends with .json route manually from within get_leaderboard_year?

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier Yes, that seems to be the way to go. Although it would be nice to be able to do it with just the attributes. I didn't find anywhere in the documentation where it says it's *not* supported, so I thought maybe it could be done.